# Creating ubuntu guest on CentOS7 host fails (VMWare SVGA unavailable)

Tags: centos, kvm, centos7, hypervisor, rhel7

Description of problem:
Importing an Ubuntu disk image fails with 'Error: VMWare SVGA not available'.
I am using KVM has a hypervisor on CentOS.

I am getting following error.

Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Error: VMWare SVGA not available
'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1855, in do_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 411, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 475, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3401, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Error: VMWare SVGA not available
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this problem by using `virt-manager` to import the guest. I checked the "Customize configuration before install" box on the last page of the wizard and chose "VGA" as the video model.

Answer (score 0):

If using 'virt-install' please specify "--video=vga"